# check if element has scroll or not - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I have `<table>` enclosed in `<div>` . Whenever we have more data the `<div>` will have vertical scroll present in that case I want to make table width 100% and if vertical scroll is not there I want to make table width 98% .

```
render() {
  return (
    <div onScroll={this.handleScroll} className="scroll-property">
      <table className="react-listing-table table" width={this.setWidth()+'%'}>
      ...
  );
}

setWidth(){
  let dom = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentNode;
  let hasVerticalScrollbar = dom.scrollHeight > dom.clientHeight;

  if (hasVerticalScrollbar) {
    return 100;
  } else {
    return 98;
  }
}
```

The problem is that  I am unable to find parent domNode i.e finding div from table  and get the runtime error

```
typeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
```

Please guide me

Comment: Could you try `.bind`ing `this.setWidth`? Seems like you're calling `findDOMNode` on the `setWidth` method, not the component.

Answer (score 2):

When `setWidth` is called inside the `render` function, the DOM doesn't actually exist yet. This is something you want to do in `componentDidMount` instead, and probably `componentDidUpdate` as well, using a ref for the table.

```
tableRef = null

render() {
  return (
    <div onScroll={this.handleScroll} className="scroll-property">
      <table className="react-listing-table table" ref={el => this.tableRef = el}>
      ...
  );
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.tableRef.width = this.setWidth() + '%'
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  this.tableRef.width = this.setWidth() + '%'
}
```